# Steady state heat equation/Laplace's equation special geometry

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh, boundary-conditions, heat-equation

I would like to solve the Laplace's equation in between the square domain and a disk. However, using the code below, I was able to generate mesh but not able to obtain results with correct boundary conditions.

The desired B.C.s are 1 at the outer boundary and 0 at inner circular boundary.

```
(*Import required FEM package*)
Remove["Global`*"]
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
With[{inner = Disk[{0, 0}, {0.25, 0.25}], 
  outer = 
   Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]}, (mesh = 
    ToElementMesh[RegionDifference[outer, inner], 
     MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001])["Wireframe"]]
sol = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 0, 
   DirichletCondition[
    u[x, y] == 1, {x, y} \[Element] RegionBoundary[outer]], 
   DirichletCondition[
    u[x, y] == 0, {x, y} \[Element] RegionBoundary[inner]]}, 
  u, {x, y} \[Element] mesh]
DensityPlot[sol[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using 'RegionBoundary' for the boundary conditions does not work well. Either specify an implicit region like in the example below or use ElementMarker.

```
(*Import required FEM package*)Remove["Global`*"]
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
With[{inner = Disk[{0, 0}, {0.25, 0.25}], 
   outer = Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]}, (mesh = 
     ToElementMesh[RegionDifference[outer, inner], 
      MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001])["Wireframe"]];
sol = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 0, 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 1, x^2 + y^2 >= 1/2], 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, x^2 + y^2 < 1/2]}, 
   u, {x, y} \[Element] mesh];
DensityPlot[sol[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Or with markers

```
(*Import required FEM package*)Remove["Global`*"]
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
With[{inner = Disk[{0, 0}, {0.25, 0.25}], 
   outer = Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]}, (mesh = 
     ToElementMesh[RegionDifference[outer, inner](*,MaxCellMeasure->
      0.001*)])["Wireframe"]];

mesh["PointElementMarkerUnion"]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9} *)

mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "PointElements", 
  "MeshElementMarkerStyle" -> Red]]
```

[image]

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 0, 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 1, ElementMarker != 5], 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, ElementMarker == 5]}, 
   u, {x, y} \[Element] mesh];
DensityPlot[sol[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

See the [Markers section in he ElementMesh Generation Tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html#180054820) for more details.

Comment: Ah! so when writing `DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 1, x^2 + y^2 >= 1/2]` then NDSolve will internally figure where the boundaries actually are, and it just needs to check that the condition `x^2 + y^2 >= 1/2` is true there or not. If the condition is true, then it will set  `u` to `1` there. I thought that one had to specify the actual boundary itself in `DirichletCondition`.  like you did with the markers. For example for unit circle, one has to say `x^2+y^2==1` to indicate the boundary is at edge of circle.  i.e. predicate has to be `==` and not `>` like you had. learned something new.